# Android Barcode Scanner Module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a Barcode Scanner peripheral attached to my phone (see attached image) and cannot seem to find a way to access the readings of the scanner. The phone is reading the barcodes as there is an emulator app within the phone which displays the numeric values of barcodes once scanned.

My question is, how can the Barcode peripheral be accessed? Similar to how the Camera is accessed via the NPM package RNCamera (React Native).

Source - [https://www.amazon.com/MUNBYN-Ergonomic-Warehouse-Inventory-Management/dp/B0885ZY3DV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0885ZY3DV)

[image: Phone]

Comment: You'll need to tell us which peripheral if you need specific advice. Having dealt with a lot of Barcode scanners, I can tell you they are usually just registered as an external keyboard for simplicity. However if this is a wireless one it might need some BLE pairing

Comment: Sure - I have updated the post with the source of the system. The documentation from the manufacturer is abysmal. To answer your query - it is not wireless, the peripheral is integrated into the device.

UPDATE - The device does use the Keyboard... Thank you for your input, would be useful if the manufacturer was aware of this. Great help.

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct SDK (https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZa7kG7ZLuWKkfz0mLY2QwLMs95XjkDv79a7) and imported it into your project?

Comment: The SDK is not compatible with React-Native. As the scanner is essential an external keyboard, a callback has been set on keyboard input and that has solved the issue

Comment: Hey @Harvvv, So did you get this working then - I see there is no accepted answer? We are wanting to use a similar Android Scanner device and want the scanner to scan into a react app using the built in Android browser. We are hoping that the scanner is just treated as another keyboard? Was there anything specific you had to do / learnings you can pass on or is it just simply a keyboard input?

Answer (score -1):

For react-native you can use this library for barcode scanner.

Library link
https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera

Here is the explanation in react-native:-

https://medium.com/@dinukadilshanfernando/implementing-a-barcode-scanner-by-using-react-native-camera-b170de4b7f51

Comment: It is correct that you can use this library for a barcode scanner. However, not for the use-case, I described. The brief outlines a Barcode peripheral - this is not a camera

Answer (score -1):

**MUNBYN Barcode Scanner Device Integration for React Native**

I had an experience with the same brand of barcode scanner and their attached scanner device acts like a keyboard actually. When it scans, it writes some texts and presses Enter automatically. After i realized it then i created a component for myself.

The idea is, you have to focus to an input. Because after scanning, some texts will be placed on somewhere, so the quick way is focus to an input and catch the scanned informations inside the input.
And also after scanning you need to handle "editing end" case, because scanner will press enter automatically. That's all you have to know actually.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Center, Spinner, Input, VStack, Button, Stack } from "native-base";

const QuickBarcodeReader = ({ getSingleCode, getArrayOfCodes, endEditingCb, inputStyle }) => {
    const [code, setCode] = useState("");
    const [codeList, setCodesList] = useState([]);
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (codeList.length > 0) getArrayOfCodes?.(codeList);
    }, [codeList]);

    const endEditing = () => {
        setCodesList(i => [...i, code]);
        inputRef?.current?.focus();
        endEditingCb?.();
        setCode("");
    };

    const textChange = text => {
        setCode(text);
        getSingleCode?.(text);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Stack w="full">
                <Stack
                    style={{ position: "absolute", width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "transparent", zIndex: 2 }}
                />
                <Input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    w="full"
                    {...inputStyle}
                    placeholder={codeList[codeList.length - 1]}
                    showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
                    autoFocus
                    value={code}
                    onChangeText={textChange}
                    onEndEditing={endEditing}
                />
            </Stack>
            <Button opacity={0} h="0" w="0" m="0" p="0" />
        </>
    );
};

export default QuickBarcodeReader;
```

For design purpose i was using native-base, so please ignore the component just focus on how i handle scanner with some functions and hooks.

I successfully created an app for pickers and delivery guys on the market.

Happy scanning, cheers...